# How to transform vue.js data in a Statamic CP form

Tags: vue.js, statamic

I have a Statamic installation v3.3.64.

I need to change a field value dynamically in a form of the Statamic control panel. Specifically, when a toggle is clicked in the same form.

I know I can show/hide a field based on a custom condition defined in resources/js/cp.js, but I cannot find a way to implement a watch event on a specific field to transform the value of another field.

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: Can you not use [Conditional Fields > Custom Logic](https://statamic.dev/conditional-fields#custom-logic) for this?

Comment: @geertjanknapen Unfortunately that only allows for hide/show functionality. Not for dynamically changing a value.

Comment: I would not know how this would be done in a neat way. What does come to mind is, if you already know the values that need to be set, you could create a field with both of the values as default, and then show or hide them based on your toggle.